# Riemann Surface Comprehension

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I have a question about an example in following script: https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/Riemann.pdf

Here the excerpt:

[image]

Why there don't exist a continuous choice of $w$ near $\pm1$ and $\pm k$? Why it does lead to the opposite choice upon return? What do they mean with return?

Above I have drawn a (in my opinion) possible choice for $w$. Why it is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your diagram is that it shows only real values of $z$ near $-1$. If you let $z$ move in a small circle in the complex plane, centered at $-1$, then the value of $\sqrt{(z^2-1)(z^2-k^2)}$ will continuously change from positive to negative on returning to $z=-1+\epsilon$ ($\epsilon>0$).

For the problem you're having, it's enough to look at the simpler surface $\sqrt{z^2-1}$. Here's a picture I created of part of it around $\pm1$:
[image: Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z^1-1}]
The x-axis runs from the bottom left to the top right. On the left, I've tried to show the "cross-cut" where the surface appears to intersect itself. (It doesn't *really* intersect itself, that's just an artifact of trying to draw the surface in regular Euclidean space. Like the circle of "self-intersection" in drawings of a Klein bottle.)

On the right hand side, I've sliced the picture along the y-axis, and display only the part with $y>0$. (When I say "x-axis" and "y-axis", I'm assuming $z=x+iy$.) In my drawing, I focussed on the situation near $1$, so let's work with that; the story near $-1$ is basically the same.

Now consider a small circle in the $z$-plane centered at $1$. Let $z$ go around that circle, starting $w$ on the upper surface. As the point passes passes through the cross-cut, it moves to the lower surface. When $z$ returns to its original position, $w$ is now minus its original value.

You can sort of see this algebraically. In $w=\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)}$, for $z$ close to 1, $z+1\approx 2$. So $\sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)}\approx\sqrt{2(z-1)}$. So near $1$, the surface should look a lot like the surface of the square root, except with the branch point at $1$ instead of $0$. (There are good pictures of the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z}$ all over the web.)

There is a reason Telemann is looking at the more complicated surface $\sqrt{(z^2-1)(z^2-k^2)}$. (*Spoiler warning!*) I've shown a portion of the surface of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ double-covering a part of the $z$ plane near the origin. The double covering can be extended to a double covering of the entire Riemann sphere. (The branch points need special attention, but I'll leave that to the textbooks.) The surface $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is topologically less interesting than the surface of $\sqrt{(z^2-1)(z^2-k^2)}$.

Finally, a recommendation: the first chapter of George Springer's *Introduction to Riemann Surfaces* has lovely pictures and a fine discussion. It's an old book, but well worth digging up.

Comment: You mean in the sense analogous to the behavior of the normal vector of Möbius strip when you walk around?

Comment: Well, sort of. I added a lot to my answer; see if the new version makes things clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. One question to your remarks at the end: The extending of the covering to the entire Riemann sphere means that to do it you have compactify  the $z$-plane by $\infty$ and consider the RS as branched covering? Or is there another reason to compactify?

Comment: You're exactly right. Adding the point at infinity and the branch points gives a compact covering. Generally speaking, compact Riemann surfaces have rather different properties from noncompact ones.

Comment: But what kind of problem occure if one don't compactify? So if one just take /find branch points and say that over other points of $z$-plane the covering (=RS) is unramified... or in other words over them the number of preimages is constant

Comment: No problems occur. But if a Riemann surface is compact, then you can prove a lot of nice theorems about it, using the compactness. One of big ones is the first theorem of Lecture 14 in Teleman's notes (p.47). Another is the Riemann-Hurwitz formula (pp.18-19). One of the first examples you'll encounter in the notes is Theorem 3.5 (p.11); also look at 4.13 and Theorem 5.1 (p.16).

Comment: Here's an analogy. A polynomial of degree $n$ usually has $n$ distinct roots in the complex plane. We could just say that *some* polynomials have fewer than $n$ roots, but it's more useful to introduce the concept of repeated roots, and count roots with multiplicity. (This is actually more than an analogy, but I don't want to go into detail in a comment.)